# render image from database in twig file

Tags: php, database, symfony, twig

I have a table MEDIA with the columns path and alt, the table POST is link to the table media. So if a user add a new post , the new post have a image id that is link to the table media. i would like to render the picture of the post in my page, but i got this error:

Here a screenshot showing the link between the table: [image]

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Notice: Undefined index: post") in
>   src\FLY\BookingsBundle\Resources\views\Post\show.html.twig at line 18.

this is what i did:

```
    {% for post in post %}
    <figure class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2">
    <span><img alt="airline" width="300" height="120" src="{{ post.image.path }}" ></span>
</figure>
{% endfor %}
```

this is my PostController.php

```
   public function showAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $findEntity = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Post')->findBy(array('user' => $user ));
        $entity  = $this->get('knp_paginator')->paginate($findEntity,$this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1),9
        );

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Post entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }
```

Comment: `showAction()` has no variable called `$post` and the array returned has no key `post` with value `$post`.  Also, `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Post')->findBy(array('user' => $user ));` adds nothing to `showAction()` - it is not assigned to any variable.

Comment: @geoB i did found a way to render the image, this is what i did : `{% for entity in entities %} <article class="box"><figure class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2">
<span><img alt="airline" width="500" height="400" src="{{ entity.image.path}}" ></span></figure>{% endfor %}`.

Comment: @ The index.html.twig it render perfectly the product with his image. the index have to show all the products of all the user's. But the page show.html.twig have to render only the product link to his ID for example: http://127.0.0.1/symfony/web/app_dev.php/post/73, but it render the product link to his ID with also the product of the user logged that are not link to the ID product.

Answer (score -1):

You are using `$entity` on `PostController` but in twig you try to use `post` which doesn't exist.

Also, you are doing a `foreach` over the variable but you should only access it because it could be only an object or null not an array